# ruby Open URL and rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to check if a few URL's exst on my old website and collect URLS that returns 404.

```
@paintings = Painting.find(:all)
@paintings.each do |painting|
  open("http://www.mydomain.com/" + painting.user.username.downcase + "/" + painting.permalink)
   rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
     @failure += painting.permalink
   else
     @success += painting.permalink
   end
  end
```

Hmmm I can't get that rescue method to pick up the error

```
syntax error, unexpected kRESCUE, expecting kEND
      rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten the `begin` prior to the open:

```
 begin
  open("http://www.mydomain.com/" + painting.user.username.downcase + "/" + painting.permalink)
 rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
   @failure += painting.permalink
 else
   @success += painting.permalink
 end
```